# Dynamic dropdownlist population using jsp and struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

In webpage , I have 3 drop down's say account ,department and manager corresponding to it. I have to fetch the total list from database . The drop down for manager which must be displayed empty at first , will dynamically populate based on the selection of account or department .Is it possible using struts 2 and jsp ?? If so , can some one explain me how it can be done ? Is there any link where I can refer ?? Please guide me as I am new to it .

Comment: Yes, it is possible using struts 2 and jsp

Comment: You can Use `ajax` call for populating manager's dropdown

Comment: Take a look at struts2-jquery plugin showcase -> select boxes